# Has anyone implemented the chain ladder method via SQL?

Tags: sql, statistics

Has anyone implemented the chain ladder method via SQL ?
It's a method used in actuarial science.

Answer (score 2):

Googling ["*chain ladder*" *SQL*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22chain+ladder%22+SQL) returns a white paper which discusses a [Transitional State Chain-Ladder](http://www.actuaries.org.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0006/26781/0479-0487.pdf) and shows a fair amount of SQL. Further down [A Practical Introduction to Actuarial Data Quality Management](http://74.125.155.132/search?q=cache:tmJM67_cUWoJ:www.casact.org/dare/documents/cpp52_1.ppt+%22chain+ladder%22+sql&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) provides discussion of the pitfalls of the various SQL query methods.

A more specific indication of what you are after would allow the community to provide a specific response. Are you looking for code examples or have you run into a specific problem? Do you simply wish to discuss mechanisms for solving the problem with SQL?

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I had to implement chain ladders in dBase IV. It's an array processing problem so I think SQL would be a bad fit.